# Alternative to QADirector

Tags: software-testing

I am looking for an alternative to [MicroFocus QADirector](http://www.microfocus.com/downloads/qadirector-6890.aspx).
The software must

- manage requirements
- manage tests
- manage test scripts (manual scripts)
- associate requirements to tests
- provide a result overview and a simple report
- run at least on Windows 7 x64 (would be nice if it also supports future version)
- cost less than 1000 € per user (not a per machine license)
- provide good keyboard input, perhaps customizable

I prefer

- one project per file
- not a web application (because the delay is too high, connectivity is sometimes bad, keyboard support is bad)

It doesn't need

- client support
- user management (I manage access on file level)
- color scheming (if it adheres to normal Windows guidelines)
- complex reporting (I'd prefer a XML export and create reports based on that)
- test agents (integration to any other test tools, I'll just maintain those results manually)
- bug tracking integration (I need to review bugs anyway, because it could be a bug in the test procedure, and enter them myself)

I have already tried:

- [TestLink](http://demo.testlink.org/latest/login.php), but I dislike the usability
- Microsoft Test Manager (TFS) is simply too big, complex, needs too many databases and servers etc.